# Azure Application Gateway DNS

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I want to set up multiple sites using Azure Application gateway. I have created 3 web apps and the listeners, rules and probes for each

> test.adomain.com which will point to azure web app
> test.azurewebsites.net
>
> live.adomain.com which will point to azure web
> app  live.azurewebsites.net
>
> preprod.adomain.com which will point to
> azure web app  prepod.websites.net

Next I then added a CNAME in my company DNS for for each of the above domains
to point to > the dns of the app gateway eg 334989--1120-8989.cloudapp.net (the  dns name in the overview page of the app gateway). so now when i navigate to test.adomain.com it correctly goes to the web app in the backend pool and the url correct shows test.adomain.com in the browser  address bar as it should.

however the other 2 domains show the url of the azure given webapp in the browser eg: when i enter in live.adomain.com it goes to the right web app but shows the url >as live.azurewebsites.net when i want it to show live.adomain.com as in the test web app above.

Not sure why this is . I have not set any custom domains up in the web app settings yet one works as it should and the other 2 although they work they display the default azure web app url instead of the company url?

Comment: To clarify your issue, could you please provide the steps to set up application gateway with web app?

Comment: I will suggest you open a support case, they can help you better in this case.